# SQL Server Express cannot connect error: 28 - Server doesn't support requested protocol

Tags: sql-server, network-protocols

I cannot connect to my local SQL Server Express (2012, but the version shouldn't matter) from my server (Windows 2008 R2) to use a tool on it (APEX SQL Data Diff if you are wondering). I can browse the network servers fine, and select my local instance from the dropdown of available servers, but when I go to search tables on the server, it times out with this error message (same is true of SSMS).

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible.  Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 28 - Server doesn't support strong text
>   requested protocol) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

I have enabled the firewall - that's not it.

I have allowed remote connections - that's not it.

SQL Server Browser service is on and passed through the firewall - that's not it.

I can connect fine with the same tools ***TO*** the server, but ***FROM*** the server it fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please mark your answer as an answer if this has solved your question.

Comment: @BernieWhite, I am not allowed to for another 22 hrs... and I thought by adding the question with an answer it would do that automatically... apparently not. This whole comment discussion belongs in (meta.serverfault.com) anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be another Stack Exchange entry on this, and no one captures the issue completely, so here it goes.

Thanks to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/22/sql-server-2005-connectivity-issue-troubleshoot-part-i.aspx) for getting me somewhere with the error message.
The issue is the necessary network protocols are disabled by default in SQL Server Express. I had to go to Sql Server Configuration Manager locally and turn on "Named Pipes" and "TCP/IP".

[image: SQL Server Config manager]

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: I don't think your screen shot is accurate.  SQLEXPRESS disables this by default but on the protocol for the instance, not the client.

Comment: @JasonCumberland, you are right. This is the screenshot _after_ I corrected them.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error while trying to connect through TCP. But TCP was already enabled and services restarted. In my case I had to enable dynamic ports on the TCP Connection:

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Setting TCP Dynamic Ports to 0 solved the issue for me, given I'd already enabled TCP in the Client Protocols dialog